# Web API without MVC framework in ASP.NET for Flex 4.6 front end

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, apache-flex, iis, asp.net-web-api

I am relatively new to development so please correct me when digressing. 
I have Flex 4.6 web application as front end for an application and a SQL Server 2008 R2 as the database on an IIS server. Currently it needs to be used over LAN but has to have the capability to be transferred over the Web.
I needs a solution for the Flex web application to connect to the DB without making direct calls from the clients. To avoid that I thought of putting in a interface using the either SOAP or Web API using ASP.NET. Problem is MVC though a solid architecture is too complex for my needs and a lot of work in case of modifications. 
My question is; is Web API dependent on the usage of MVC for it to be implemented or can plain ASP.NET work?
If it does work on ASP.NET; do I still need to create models and controllers in the plain ASP.NET project?
If I decide for an authentication, what approaches are available that I can look into that will be efficient?
Any other solutions or suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

ASP.NET Web API doesn't depend on ASP.NET MVC. To be more accurate, it doesn't even depend on System.Web. Have a look:

[ASP.NET Web API does not Sit on Top of ASP.NET MVC! In Fact, It does not Sit on Top of Anything](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/newsflash-asp-net-web-api-does-not-sit-on-top-of-asp-net-mvc-in-fact-it-does-not-sit-on-top-of-anything)

Comment: Can you provide me with some examples on how can I get an Web API up and running on a IIS server?